# How to find average for each column in file c++

Tags: c++, average

I have a file that contains rows and columns

2456  128  234  67

2368  200  249  70

2655  212  250  89

I need to find the average for each column. This is what I try :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string input;
ifstream namefile("payment.txt");

if (!namefile)
return (cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n"), 1;
while (getline(namefile, input))
cout << input << endl;

namefile.clear();
namefile.seekg(0);

int a {}, b {}, c {}, d {};
namefile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

int price1 = a;
int price2 = b;
int price3 = c;
int price4 = d;

for (a = 0; a < 3 ; a++)
{
   int total = a ;
   a++;
   price1 = a/3;
}

  std::cout << "The average price for A is " << price1 << '\n';

for (b = 0; b < 3 ; b++)
{
   int total = b ;
   b++;
   price2 = b/3;
}

  std::cout << "The average price for B is " << price2 << '\n';
}
```

I try to run this coding but it did not works. Does anyone know how to make it work? Please help me

Comment: what is the meaning of "did not works" ?

Comment: There is just too much wrong in this code. I would expect to see `namefile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;` in a loop, but instead you call it only once. Also it is not clear how the loop over `a` is supposed to calcuate average of entries from the file. The loop starts at `a=0` does some stuff and after the loop `price1` is always `2/3` which is `0`. Don't try to write all the code at once. You could for example try to write code that calculates average of some hardcoded numbers. Once you got that right, you can add more

Comment: Side note: When you have sequentially named or numbered variables, often the code will be simpler with an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your program can be simplified:

```
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0; 
int sum3 = 0;
int sum4 = 0;
int p1, p2, p3, p4;
int quantity = 0;
while (namefile >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> p4)
{
  sum1 += p1;
  sum2 += p2;
  sum3 += p3;
  sum4 += p4;
  ++quantity;
}
if (quantity > 0)
{
    const double average1 = (double) sum1 / quantity;
    const double average2 = (double) sum2 / quantity;
    const double average3 = (double) sum3 / quantity;
    const double average4 = (double) sum4 / quantity;
    std::cout << average1
              << " " << average2
              << " " << average3
              << " " << average4
              << "\n";
}
```

You may also want to try the same program, using `std::vector<int>` instead of separate variables.